# Android fingerprint authenticate KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure() check

Tags: android, security, fingerprint

Following [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-add-fingerprint-authentication/) on fingerprint authentication I  should check for `KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()` before letting users authenticate with fingerprint.

Why should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Most device manufacturers require a secure lock screen type (PIN, password, pattern) in order to use fingerprints. When changing the lock screen type to an insecure one (None, Swipe or other mode which does not authenticate the user) the fingerprints are removed.

On Samsung devices this is handled differently, by providing the user the possibility to not delete the fingerprints (and secure them with an additional password). Thereby, the user can still use the fingerprints in applications.

In case you want to allow those users, with a Samsung device, to use fingerprint authentication (in your app) even though they don't have set a secure lock screen type, you don't need to check if `KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Later in the code, the tutorial uses [setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)), which won't work if there is no secure keyguard.

Comment: On Samsung devices setUserAuthenticationRequired(true) is ignored.. If there is no lock screen option set, the generated Key should not work, but it does.